# Show specific paragraphs (labels) Using ComboBoxes

Tags: c#, combobox, label

I want to be able to take user input from a ComboBox and display a specific paragraph written using a label.

Now this course I'm taking only told me how to retrieve the info from the box and then display it using `MessageBox.Show` I'm not sure how to do this, as my book doesn't explain this.

Basically all I have is a `ComboBox` on a form right now and it has a list of Months from which to choose.

I want to be ale to display the correct paragraph according to the month they chose. I know how to retrieve the selection, but I don't know how use that information to display the paragraph on the form.

```
 private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        switch (comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString())
        {

            case "January":
                label1.Text = "write something about january...";
                break;
            case "February":
                label1.Text = "write something about February..";
                break;

        }

    }
```

EDIT: Ok I got this working. I just gotta move the label to the correct position.

Comment: When you say `paragraph`, what do you mean by that *exactly?*

Comment: Where did you store your all paragraphs? in a string,or txt file,or seperate files?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!  This question needs to show the code you've created that shows your problem.  Please edit your question to add the code.

Comment: Like I said, I'm new to this. Right now I just visually created a label from the toolbox and have all the paragraphs on the same form page with a scrollbar.

Comment: I have no idea. I was using the code given to me below. But yeah Sorry. I was going to post the many errors i got soon. I had to get off for a second. But yes that was the problem. When i pasted the code i forgot the beginning half...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want something like this:

```
switch (comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString())
        {
            case "January":
                label1.Text = "write something about january...";
                break;
            case "February":
                label1.Text = "write something about February..";
                break;

            // and so on...
        }
```

You can use switch statement,and display different messages in the label depends on selected month...

Comment: Ok this works Thanks, but when i make my selection the text appears right on top of the Combobox.

Comment: add another label and display text in it or move your label1 to different location